# List drag'n'drop and TextInput focus priority

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm using a Spark List with a TextInput in the ItemRenderer, with ability for the user to reorder the list rows by drag'n'dropping them. This is how I declared the list :

```
<s:List id="list" left="245" top="119" width="667" height="433"
                dragDrop="insertItem(event)" dragEnabled="true" dragEnter="acceptDrop(event)" dragComplete="finalizeDragAndMove(event)"
                dragMoveEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true" focusAlpha="0"
                skinClass="components.DataList_Campaign"
                hasFocusableChildren="true" />
```

Everything works fine, except that it's impossible to select the text in the TextInput with the mouse, instead it's dragging the row...How can I set the TextInput to have priority over drag'n'drop ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'having priority' ?

Comment: Actually I would like to be able to select the entire text in the TextInput with the mouse, but I can't because "priority" (maybe it's not the most appropriate term) is given to the list : I can only drag the row, even when the TextInput has the focus...

Answer (score 1):

In your TextInput item renderer just declare 2 events like this:
`<s:TextInput focusIn="outerDocument.list.dragEnabled=false"
                                                     focusOut="outerDocument.list.dragEnabled=true"/>`
hope this will help...

Comment: Unluckily it seems that outerDocument only exists for inline item renderers, which is not the case in my application.

Comment: @jroy In your case also when your itemrenderer textinput got focus you have to do your lists dragEnabled property to set false then while focus out you have to do true. just show your item renderer code you can handle it by dispatching some events.